# Invoking Java web service from C# client using JKS and/or PFX certificates

Tags: c#, java, ssl, request, certificate

I basically need to secure my requests towards this service.

I've been provided a `JAR` test client and two files, `trust.jks` and `Client.pfx`, but I have no clue how to use them: I understand X509Certificate2 class is involved in some way.

The command line to execute the test client is the following:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=******** -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=Client.pfx -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=******** -jar TestClient.jar https://myServiceurl
```

It works, so I can both see the service, and the service itself should be properly configured.

My C# client (it's targeting .NET 2.0) uses a normal Web Reference to perform requests:

```
wsReferenceClient service = new wsReferenceClient();
//certificate code here ?
//maybe service.ClientCertificates.Add(<X509Certificate2 object built somehow>); ?
service.MyRequest(myParameters);
```

Server settings should be setup properly.

I fumbled around with the `X509Certificate2` methods but I can't come out with something that makes sense, so the answer to the 'what have you tried?' question at the moment is 'I don't really know what to try in the first place'.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK the JKS store is a proprietary Java solution. You must export the public keys (maybe the whole chain) using keytool and import it into an open format store like PKCS.

Comment: Correct, allthough I would rather take the trusted certificates from it separately and use those. The pfx already should contain the private key and cert chain.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I need to make the JKS file edible to my client in some way ? Think I'll google around a bit more ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I don't need to do anything with the `JKS` file.

```
wsReferenceClient service = new wsReferenceClient();
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import("Client.pfx", "<the password>", DefaultKeySet);
service.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
service.MyRequest(myParameters);
```

This allows my HTTPS requests to go through successfully.

Comment: Do you mean X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet