# How can I read JKS file in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have been requested from my partner to use his API, and to use this API, I should encrypt all sent data to **AES 256**. He shared a **.jks** file with me, in addition to some parameters with values like (**Alias, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD and KEY_PASSWORD**), then he told me that the password which I should use for encryption is stored in that JKS file, and to open it, I should use the pre-shared parameters.

So, how can I reach that?

**UPDATE** ...
This is not a web service am trying to invoke, I just need to get the **Password** which is stored in the JKS file, so, I am not going to invoke an API or import a certificate into my client app. So, it doesn't matter if opening the app by C# or any other tool, i just need to get the password in order to use it later in encrypting some data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking Java web service from C# client using JKS and/or PFX certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138333/invoking-java-web-service-from-c-sharp-client-using-jks-and-or-pfx-certificates)

Comment: I passed by it before submitting this question, but it didn't help me. Anyways, I solved it, and thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened the given file by using [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/), then I imported the file into the app and providing it with all shared info like KeyStore_Password and Key_Password. Eventually, it opens.

I know that is away off C#, but all what I needed is to get the **Password** which is stored in that file, and this was my first time to deal with something like that.

Comment: Are you sure that this app is secure?

Answer (score 0):

But you cannot access "TrustedCertEntry". It is a restriction.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallProbs