# How to add JKS file to HttpClient request

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to send http requests with a cert, 
when in using the SoapUi I'm adding a JKS file to the request and it works great, and now I'm trying to implement this in .Net Core code. 
I'm using `HttpClient` for the request and I don't know how can I attach the JKS file.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JKS` is a Java  proprietary format for key stores, used by default until Java8. Since Java9 the default format is PCKS#12.

C# can not read this kind of files, but it is easy to convert from JKS to PKCS#12 using keytool or KeystoreExplore

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <jks_file_name.jks> -destkeystore <pk12_file_name.p12> -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass <password>
```

See this answer to invoke a http service using client certificates https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170573/6371459